# Good day all, i was able to create a nested subfolder in outlook but now i am having a hard time to move the same folder to another folder?

Tags: vb.net

Public Sub CreateOutlookFolder(worksheetnumber As String, repinit As String, worksheetname As String)
'This is working fine
Dim outlookfoldername As String
Dim App = New Outlook.Application
Dim Inbox = App.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox)
Dim Exception As String

```
    outlookfoldername = "WS" & worksheetnumber & " - " & repinit & " - " & worksheetname

    Try
        ' CREATE A NEW FOLDER INSIDE INBOX FILE FOLDER
        Inbox.Folders.Item("#1 WORKSHEET").Folders.Item("NEW").Folders.Add(outlookfoldername)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Exception = ex.Message
        MsgBox(Exception, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    End Try
    ' CLEANUP
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(Inbox)
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(App)
End Sub
```

Public Sub MoveOutlookFlder(worksheetnumber As String, repinit As String, wsname As String, oldstatus As String, newstatus As String)
Dim movefrom As String
Dim moveto As String
Dim Exception As String
Exception = ""

```
    movefrom = "WS" & worksheetnumber & " - " & repinit & " - " & wsname
    moveto = "WS" & worksheetnumber & " - " & repinit & " - " & wsname
    ' Open Outlook
    Dim App = New Outlook.Application

    'Get Inbox folders
    Dim Inbox = App.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox)

    ' Move it from Inbox to Drafts
    'Inbox.Folders.Item(foldername).MoveTo(Drafts)

    Try
        'HERE IS THE PLOBLEM
        'MOVE THE FOLDER FROM THE OLD STATUS FOLDER TO THE NEW STATUS FOLDER
        Inbox.Folders.Item(movefrom).MoveTo(Inbox.Folders.Item("#1 
        WORKSHEET").Folders.Item(newstatus))
    Catch ex As Exception
        Exception = ex.Message
        MsgBox(Exception, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    End Try
    ' Cleanup
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(Inbox)
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(App)
End Sub
```

Comment: And what exactly is the problem?

Comment: good day Hursey, the moveto doesn't work it gives me an error (The attempted operation failed. an object could not be found.